# using 64 bits Informix CSDK with gcc in AIX?

Tags: informix

I don't think this configuration is supported (maybe gcc isn't supported at all) because the esql script uses xlc options only.

But I want to know if other people are using this configuration gcc and informix 64 bits in AIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ESQL/C (a part of ClientSDK or CSDK) to use GCC, but it isn't completely trivial.  In principle, what I do is:

1. Make a copy of the original esql script.
2. Modify the original script to supply the GCC options on demand.

If you only want to use GCC, then this is sufficient.  If you want to use both GCC and sometimes XLC (the native compiler), then it is harder.

I have a single script called esql in my private bin directory (which is always on my PATH ahead of things like $INFORMIXDIR/bin).  It works out which version of ESQL/C I'm currently using, and runs the appropriate pre-patched version which is stored in a separate directory.  And it automatically creates new versions of that script for me so if I work with CSDK 3.00.UC2 one minute and then CSDK 3.50.FC3 the next, it handles the switchover automatically.

Here's the patch applied to ESQL/C 3.50 on Solaris - you'll need to adapt it to AIX.

```
# @(#)$Id: patch.300.64,v 1.2 2007/09/02 21:46:55 jleffler Exp $
# GCC Patch for esql from CSDK 3.00.FC1

--- esql        2007-09-02 14:44:18.739067000 -0700
+++ esql.new    2007-09-02 14:44:26.812149000 -0700
@@ -23,10 +23,33 @@
 INFDIR=${INFORMIXDIR=/usr/informix}
 DB2CLIDIR=${INSTHOME=/usr/db2}
 PREPCC=${INFDIR}/lib/esql/esqlc
-CC="${INFORMIXC=cc} -xarch=v9"
-CC_TH="${INFORMIXC=cc} -xarch=v9"
-CPP="${INFORMIXCPP=CC} -xarch=v9"
-CPP_TH="${INFORMIXCPP=CC} -xarch=v9"
+
+: ${INFORMIXC:=cc}
+: ${INFORMIXCPP:=CC}
+case "$INFORMIXC" in
+*perl*esqlcc*)  # Building DBD::Informix
+    case "$ESQLCC" in
+    *gcc*|*g++)
+        CC_ARCHFLAGS="-m64"
+        ;;
+    *cc*|*CC*)
+        CC_ARCHFLAGS="-xarch=v9"
+        ;;
+    esac
+    ;;
+*gcc*|*g++*)
+    CC_ARCHFLAGS="-m64"
+    ;;
+# Beware - this normally needs to be last - because things like esqlcc and gcc match too!
+*cc*|*CC*)
+    CC_ARCHFLAGS="-xarch=v9"
+    ;;
+esac
+
+CC="$INFORMIXC $CC_ARCHFLAGS"
+CC_TH="$INFORMIXC $CC_ARCHFLAGS"
+CPP="$INFORMIXCPP $CC_ARCHFLAGS"
+CPP_TH="$INFORMIXCPP $CC_ARCHFLAGS"
 STATICFLAGS=""

 CP=${INFORMIXCP="$CC -E -C"}                    # cpp which runs before esqlc
@@ -51,9 +74,6 @@
 then 
 CC="$CC $CC_AMD32"
 CPP="$CPP $CC_AMD32"
-else 
-CC=$CC
-CPP=$CPP
 fi

 : '
@@ -922,7 +942,7 @@
                # Set the linker to CPP
                # Set the source files to objects
                #
-               CC=$CPP
+               CC="$CPP"
                A="$AO $CPPOPTS"
        fi
 fi
```

Lemme know if you want the controlling `esql` script that I use (see my profile).  I have 9 32-bit scripts and 8 64-bit scripts, created by a set of 12 different patch files (all for Solaris, I'm afraid).  The versions range from ESQL/C 5.20 (for OnLine 5.20) via ESQL/C 7.2x (long dead officially) through various versions of CSDK.